# Span of Dirac's delta distributions dense in Hilbert space of $L^2$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

According to Wiki a set of elements of a Hilbert space(B) is a basis for that space if:

1. Orthogonality: Every two different elements of $B$ are orthogonal:
   $⟨e_k,e_j⟩=0$ for all $k$, $j$ in $B$ with $k\neq j$.
2. Normalization:Every element of the family has norm 1: $⟨e_k,e_k⟩=1$
   for all $k$ in $B$.
3. Completeness: The linear span of the family $\{e_k \mid k\in B\}$ is
       dense set in $H$.

Take the Hilbert space to be the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Dirac delta functions satisfy the first and second property. Are they densely defined over $B=L^2{(\mathbb{R})}$? It appears to me that it should, since a linear combination of them with the inner product of $L^2$ can make them as close as one wants to a function in $L^2$ because of their point evaluation property. Am I missing something? I couldn't find a reference acknowledging this!

**EDIT**:
As it has been clarified in comments, Dirac deltas are not even functions. I wonder what is then the natural extension of Kronecker deltas(standard basis) to infinite dimensions? (If one sees any finite dimension vector as a discrete function over its index set)

Comment: How do you identify Dirac deltas with elements of $L_2$?

Comment: @TomekKania: I think he means dirac delta in the physicists sense of the word

Comment: Yes I am sorry its not a function but its a distribution. Although now I start to doubt even the second condition holds.

Comment: $\delta$ fails on the zeroth count, $\delta \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer right. What I am wondering is then what is the extension of Kronecker delta of finite dimensional spaces to infinite dimensions?

Comment: There is no "standard basis" except for vector spaces $\mathbb{K}^n$ (where $\mathbb{K}$ is an arbitrary field). Even finite-dimensional spaces of a different form don't have a "standard basis".

Comment: Delta functions cannot be applied to general $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ functions because an element of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the same if you change the function on any set of measure zero. For you could change the function on every rational number and it's still the same. So there's not a good way apply $\delta$ to functions in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer the spaces $\Bbb R_n[X]$ beg to differ=)

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Not sure what space that denotes, but yeah, the spaces of polynomials also have a distinguished basis one may rightly call "standard".